# Regex, if there is something there, make sure it isn't something

Tags: regex

Sorry for the vague title, I have to do this a lot and I avoid REGEX (directly, I end up wrapping it) and I now think it's too common not to have been addressed.

Backslash escaping! I am replacing text between %% and a closing %% with something, but I want to be able to write %%.

I want to say IF there is something before %% then make sure it isn't a \ , for example:

`[^\]%%` wont work, because it wont get things at the start of the string.

`[^\]?%%` wont work because if it is a backslash, it's optional.

---

I just had a thought while writing this!

`/(?:(?:(?:\\\\{2})+)|[^\\\\])%%(.*)%%/` (note `\\` is the letter backslash in the regex.

Read this as "(a nonzero even number of backslashes OR not a backslash) followed by %% ...."

Without testing you can see this wont work, as given `\\\%%stuff%%` the Regex engine will see `\\%%stuff%%` (after the first `\` which IS an even number)

So

`/(?:(?:[^\\\\](?:\\\\{2})+)|[^\\\\])%%(.*)%%/` seems the next step, this says

"((not a backslash) followed by an even number of backslashes OR not a backslash) followed by %%..."

Which is closer! We have the start-of-string problem now, we may also factor the regex to get:

`/(?:[^\\\\](?:\\\\{2})*)%%(.*)%%/` which is "not a backslash followed by any even number of backslashes followed by %%...." which is almost great!

I then discovered some magic, because this is SO CLOSE and as I said I cannot believe this has not been done, see answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know, at least with PERL regex, `^` means start-of-string (when not found in classes), and `$` means end. These are great because they mean rules like `^a` matches strings (or sometimes lines) that start with a, rather than the first a it finds anywhere.

It suddenly hit me, there's no technical difficulties in having "start of string" as an input and transitioning states based on it! (Regexes are compiled to "deterministic finite automata - state machines!) so I thought I'd test it with an ^, so now it is "(not-backslash followed by even number of backslashes OR start of string) followed by %%...."

`/(?:(?:[^\\\\](?:\\\\{2})+)|[^\\\\]|^)%%(.*)%%/` which can be written as (by recognising the case of 0 backslashes, and that 0 is even) as

`(?:(?:[^\\\\](?:\\\\{2})*)|^)%%(.*)%%/`

Hope this helps somebody

**You can use `^` anywhere**

Can't believe all those times I sidestepped solving this!